# Error when using mshapiro.test: "U[] is not a matrix with number of columns (sample size) between 3 and 5000"

Tags: r, anova

I am trying to perform a multivariate test for normality on some density data from five sites, using mshapiro.test from the `mvnormtest` package. Each site is a column, and densities are below. It is 5 columns and 5 rows, with the top row as the header (site names). Here is how I loaded my data:

```
datafilename="/Users/megsiesiple/Documents/Lisa/lisadensities.csv"
data.nc5=read.csv(datafilename,header=T)
attach(data.nc5)`
```

The data look like this:

```
       B07      B08      B09      B10        M  
1 72571.43 17714.29  3142.86 22571.43  8000.00
2 44571.43 46857.14 49142.86 16857.14  7142.86
3 54571.43 44000.00 26571.43  6571.43 17714.29
4 57714.29 38857.14 32571.43  2000.00  5428.57
```

When I call mshapiro.test() for data.nc5 I get this message: `Error in mshapiro.test(data.nc5) : 
  U[] is not a matrix with number of columns (sample size) between 3 and 5000`

I know that to perform a Shapiro-Wilk test using `mshapiro.test()`, the data has to be in a numeric matrix, with a number of columns between 3 and 5000. However, even when I make the .csv a matrix with only numbers (i.e., when I omit the Site names), I still get the error. Do I need to set up the matrix differently? Has anyone else had this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: depending on what you're doing it's unnecessary and often dis-recommended to `attach(data.nc5)` (it's easy to get confused when using `attach`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the numeric matrix into R via `read.csv()` using similar code to that you do show, it will be read in as a data frame, and that is not a matrix.

Try

```
mat <- data.matrix(data.nc5)
mshapiro.test(mat)
```

(Not tested as you don't give a reproducible example and it is late-ish in my time zone now ;-)

Comment: Yeehaw! It worked! Next time I'll show the example... I wasn't sure whether to paste as an image or something else. Thanks, Gavin.

Comment: @Margaret: For a 5 x 5 object just post output from dput(data.nc5), and don't forget to give Gavin his checkmark. Not that he needs it, but it's good manners.

Comment: @Margaret if you are happy with an Answer, please Accept it (check the big tick mark next to the Answer). This tells others that might have the same or similar problem that one of the provided Answers solved the problem. This adds considerably to the value of the StackOverflow site as a useful repository of Answers/Advice

Comment: @Gavin- Thanks. I also edited to add dataset, for others' edification.

Answer (score 4):

You need to transpose the data in a matrix, so that your variables are in rows, and observations in columns. The command will be :

M <- t(data.nc5[1:4,1:5])

mshapiro.test(M)

It works for me this way. The labels in the first row should be recognized during the import, so the data will start from row 1. Otherwise, there will be a "missing value" error.